# Laravel / Envoyer.io Deployment - MetadataBag Not found

Tags: git, laravel, cpanel, whm, envoyer.io

I have set up a new laravel application with Envoyer.io deployment. But when im deploying the files from GIT to the server trough Envoyer, i keep getting this error:

[image]

We have tried fresh reinstalls with no configuration with several methods, and they always work locally. Its only when we Deploy with Envoyer, we get this error.

We tried manually uploading the files to the right folders, and then the site worked perfectly fine. So its only when Envoyer does the "uploading".

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Were running a Dedicated Linux server with WHM/Cpanel, and we already have 2 other laravel applications running fine trough Envoyer, but on other Cpanel accounts on the server.

Comment: According to this video (https://laracasts.com/series/envoyer/episodes/1) from 5:10 it shows you can see and copy the composer output. Can you add that to your question?

Comment: We found the error. Somehow the Vendor folders were incomplete. So all good, thanks for your time

Comment: If you think the resolution you found would be helpful to other users, feel free to [self-answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question. Otherwise, you can [delete your post](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).